# Spark Streaming job get killed after running for about 1 hour

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job that read tweets stream from gnip and write it to Kafak.

Spark and kafka are running on the same cluster.

My cluster consists of 5 nodes. Kafka-b01 ... Kafka-b05

Spark master is running on Kafak-b05.

Here is how we submit the spark job

**nohup sh $SPZRK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --total-executor-cores 5 --class com.test.java.gnipStreaming.GnipSparkStreamer --master spark://kafka-b05:7077 GnipStreamContainer.jar powertrack kafka-b01,kafka-b02,kafka-b03,kafka-b04,kafka-b05 gnip_live_stream 2 &**

After about 1 hour the spark job get killed

The logs in the nohub file shows the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockFetchException: Failed to fetch block from 2 locations. Most recent failure cause: 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:595) 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585) 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemote(BlockManager.scala:570) 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:630) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.compute(BlockRDD.scala:48) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Unable to create Channel from class class io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$BootstrapChannelFactory.newChannel(AbstractBootstrap.java:455) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:306) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doConnect(Bootstrap.java:134) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:116) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:211) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:90) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:120) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:99) 
        at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:89) 
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:588) 
        ... 15 more 
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket. 
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:62) 
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:72) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$BootstrapChannelFactory.newChannel(AbstractBootstrap.java:453) 
        ... 26 more 
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files 
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method) 
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:411) 
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:404) 
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:105) 
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60) 
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:60) 
        ... 33 more
```

I have increased the maximum number of open files to 3275782 (the old number was almost half of this number) but I am still facing the same issue.

When I checked the `stderr` logs of the workers from spark web interface I found another exception.

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException 
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:110) 
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:75) 
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:74) 
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:119) 
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:59) 
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82) 
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.getBrokerPartitionInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:49) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$getPartitionListForTopic(DefaultEventHandler.scala:188) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:152) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$partitionAndCollate$1.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:151) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) 
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.partitionAndCollate(DefaultEventHandler.scala:151) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:96) 
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:73) 
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77) 
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33) 
        at com.test.java.gnipStreaming.GnipSparkStreamer$1$1.call(GnipSparkStreamer.java:59) 
        at com.test.java.gnipStreaming.GnipSparkStreamer$1$1.call(GnipSparkStreamer.java:51) 
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:225) 
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:225) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920) 
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(RDD.scala:920) 
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) 
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The second exception (as it seems) is related to Kafka not spark.

What do you think the problem is?

EDIT

based on a comment from Yuval Itzchakov Here is the code of the streamer

The main class http://pastebin.com/EcbnQQ3a

The customer receiver class http://pastebin.com/3UFPktKR

Comment: You need to show us the code that writes to Kafka. The number of concurrent connections shouldn't exceed the number of partitions per topic that you've set in Kafka. Increasing the number of file handles is only a patch, you're most likely doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: Thnx Yuval, I added two links for the code. By the way, when I submit the same job to a local spark installation, it works fine without any problem. I am suspecting the existence of Kafka on the same Spark cluster to be the root cause of this issue. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're instantiating a new instance of `Producer` on the iteration of `DStream.foreachPartition`. In case you have a data intensive stream, this can cause a-lot of producers to be allocated and attempt to connect to Kafka.

The first thing I'd make sure is that you're properly closing the stream once you're done sending the data using a `finally` block and calling [`producer.close`](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html):

```
public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
    rdd.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
       
        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<String> itr) throws Exception {
            try {
                Producer<String, String> producer = getProducer(hosts);
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    try {
                        KeyedMessage<String, String> message = 
                        new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic, itr.next());
                        producer.send(message);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } finally {
                  producer.close()
            }
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

If that still doesn't work and you're seeing too many connections, I'd create an object pool for Kafka producers which you can pool for on demand. That way, you explicitly control the number of available producers in use and the number of sockets you open.

Comment: I added the producer.close() line and the job is working smoothly 14 hour ago. Thanks Yuval.

Comment: Yuval, closing the producer makes the job running all the time but now the stderr of the workers is full of "kafka.producer.ProducerClosedException: producer already closed" Exception. Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: Are you closing them in the finally block?

Comment: Yes, Exactly as you mentioned. I did two changes that solved all of my problems. The first one is to use --executor-memory 2G when submitting the job. The other is to close the producer outside the while loop. The job is running 4 hours till now and there is no exceptions at all in the stderr.

Comment: @Fanooos Whoops, I forgot we were inside an iterator. Of course that's the fix :) Adding a `try-finally` outside the loop.